# Displaying a list of Websites in a drop down

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore

In my Magento 1.9, I have the below snippet that gives me the list of "Stores" that are available in **one Single Website** as a drop down format.

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>

<div class="header-button lang-list full_mode">

    <div class="header-button-title"> <span class="current"><?php $locale = Mage::app()->getStore()->getName(); echo $locale; ?></span></div>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
        <?php $_selected = ($_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId()) ? ' class="selected"' : '' ?>
        <li>
            <a <?php echo $_selected ;?> href="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getLocaleCode()) ?>"><span><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?></span><span class="mobile-part"><?php echo substr($this->htmlEscape($_lang->getLocaleCode()), 0, 2) ?></span></a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I am trying to change the above logic by displaying the list of **Stores** that are across different **Websites**.

**Because, I have 2 websites, and there are 1 store in each of them**

I have tried replacing *`getStores()`* with *`getWebsites()`* but didn't work.

Comment: have you tried Mage::app()->getWebsites() ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
<?php
$websites = Mage::app()->getWebsites();

if (count($websites) > 1): ?>
<div class="website-switcher">
    <label for="select-website"><?php echo $this->__('Select Store:') ?></label>
    <select id="select-website" title="<?php echo $this->__('Select Store') ?>" onchange="location.href=this.value">
    <?php foreach ($websites as $website): // print out each website name and code as a dropdown box item ?>
        <?php $_selected = $website->getCode() == Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getCode() ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $website->getDefaultStore()->getBaseUrl()?>"<?php echo $_selected ?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($website->getName()) ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I hope, it should work.

Comment: Technically your solution is what I was looking for, but it messed up my UI as it doesn't follow the HTML tags I provided in my snippet, neither I have an idea how to do so.